# SSRS printing rogue lines

Tags: reporting-services, printing

I have created an SSRS report which includes a company logo embedded in the report header.  When the report is printed, two lines show up in the printout that are not in the design of the report.  It's like it is printing the textbox borders, but I have the borders set to none.  Has anyone seen this, and do you know how to make them go away?

Picture 1:  Design View of the report

[image: Design View]

Picture 2:  Preview of the report (looks normal)

[image: Preview]

Picture 3:  Print Layout of the report (how it looks printed to paper or to PDF) - notice the two lines show up

[image: Print Layout/Print Preview]

Answer (score 0):

You probably do actually have the borders set up to be displayed.

Open the border settings for the areas of your table on both sides of the border as well as the the border settings for the picture itself.

When you have a table with different borders settings specified for adjacent items, it is a bit of a crapshoot as to which shows up.

If that is not the case, I would try loading the image in another part of the report to see if the lines follow it.  Depending on what happens there, you will know where the problem originates.